# Hw do I clck the add btn and it display the info in the input field and display it n a <p> created with JS. (no inline JS)

Tags: javascript

Im trying to take the user input and add it to the page with the click of the button and add it to the page in a new paragraph element created thru javascript, I didn't want to use any inline javascript and I wanted to use as little html as possible and do it mainly thru javascript.

```
<body>
<div class="input">
    <form>
        <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter task to do..." />
        <button id="add_btn">Add</button>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="task_list">
    <ul id="todo">
        <li></li>
    </ul>

</div>


<script>
   //take user input and add it to the page as a task to do
   let div = document.querySelector('.task_list');
   let input = document.querySelector('#input')
   let pElement = document.createElement('p');
   let add = document.getElementById('add_btn');

   div.appendChild(pElement);

    add.addEventListener(onclick, function (){
        input.value;
        pElement.innerHTML = input;
        console.log(add);
    });

 </script>
```

Comment: `add.addEventListener(onclick` is not how you add a listener - check your console. Also, `input.value;` on a standalone line isn't doing anything at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got some problems with your code:

1. You're wrongly binding the event listener. You should use `'click'` instead of `onclick` (which isn't defined anyway).
2. You didn't define any button type, so the button is treated as submit button, by default. Add `type="button"` attribute so that the page doesn't refresh on clicking on it.
3. In the event listener, you should create a fresh `p` element always, and assign its `textContent` with `input.value` (unless you're dealing with HTML content, in which case, `innerHTML` would be appropriate).

The following snippet makes the code work. Not sure what end result should be like (e.g. you may want to append the list items in `ul`), but this can get you on track.

```js
//take user input and add it to the page as a task to do
let div = document.querySelector('.task_list');
let input = document.querySelector('#input')
let add = document.getElementById('add_btn');

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let pElement = document.createElement('p');
  pElement.textContent = input.value;
  div.appendChild(pElement);
});
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <form>
    <input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Enter task to do...">
    <button type="button" id="add_btn">Add</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div class="task_list">
  <ul id="todo">
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```